# Missing "WMSJSProject" in Windows8 app

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8

All,

I'm inheriting a Windows8 app but can't get the project to open in Visual Studio. Essentially, the line below from the project is invalid because I'm missing something:

It's resolving out to:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio..Default.props"

What ever "$(WMSJSProject)" resolves to is not installed. I'm assuming it is some sort of extension or 3rd party tool, but I can't find a solid reference to it.

Anyone have any thoughts on what I am missing?

Thanks!

-Cord

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue ?